# Compare a Cultures region without creating a RegionInfo from LCID

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

For listing the applicable cultures for the given region, this is my current code:

```
public IEnumerable<CultureInfo> ForRegion(RegionInfo regionInfo)
{
     return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
          .Where(c => Equals(new RegionInfo(c.LCID), regionInfo));
}
```

But I don't like having to create a `RegionInfo` in the `Where`.

I really want to do something this:

```
public IEnumerable<CultureInfo> ForRegion(RegionInfo regionInfo)
{
     return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
          .Where(c => c.LCID == regionInfo.LCID);
}
```

But as there isn't an `LCID` on `RegionInfo` I can't. Aside from a better solution it would be interesting to know why a `RegionInfo` doesn't have an `LCID`.

## Example test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_find_all_by_region_ES_valencia()
{
    var regionInfo = new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("ca-ES-valencia").LCID);
    List<CultureInfo> found = ForRegion(regionInfo).ToList();
    Assert.AreEqual(5, found.Count);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(
        new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("ca-ES"),
            new CultureInfo("ca-ES-valencia"), //missing with Jon's solution
            new CultureInfo("es-ES"),
            new CultureInfo("eu-ES"),
            new CultureInfo("gl-ES")
        },
        found);
}
```

This works for my current solution but not Jon's.

Another two tests, fails for Jon's modified solution (work for original):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_find_all_by_region_Germany()
{
    List<CultureInfo> found = ForRegion(new RegionInfo("DE")).ToList();
    Assert.AreEqual(3, found.Count);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(
        new[] {new CultureInfo("de-DE"), new CultureInfo("dsb-DE"), new CultureInfo("hsb-DE")}, found);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Round_trip_all_cultures()
{
    foreach (CultureInfo culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
        Assert.IsTrue(ForRegion(new RegionInfo(culture.LCID)).Contains(culture), culture.Name);
}
```

Comment: Bill Bryson: "a language is a dialect with an army and a navy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Skeet pointed out, `RegionInfo`s are compared by `Name`. When you create a `RegionInfo` from an `LCID`, the name actually comes from a property on a `CultureData` it has found by `LCID`.

So I have added an extension method that efficiently (for my purposes at least, i.e. in my solution I need to create each Region once anyway) gets the region name from a culture.

```
public static class CultureInfoExtension
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> RegionNamesByLcid =
        CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            .Select(c => c.LCID)
            .Distinct()
            .ToDictionary(lcid => lcid, lcid => new RegionInfo(lcid).Name);

    private static string FallbackToThrowConsistentException(CultureInfo c)
    {
        return new RegionInfo(c.LCID).Name;
    }

    public static string GetRegionName(this CultureInfo c)
    {
        string name;
        return RegionNamesByLcid.TryGetValue(c.LCID, out name)
            ? name
            : FallbackToThrowConsistentException(c);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public IEnumerable<CultureInfo> ForRegion(RegionInfo regionInfo)
{
    return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
        .Where(c => CultureBelongsToRegion(c, regionInfo));
    }

    private static bool CultureBelongsToRegion(CultureInfo c, RegionInfo regionInfo)
    {
        return c.GetRegionName() == regionInfo.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be quite obvious from the results you get from your query - the same region can have multiple locales (and thus, LCIDs). So at best, you could get a *list* of LCIDs for a given region - and if you want to maintain that list, just make it yourself.

For example, region `GB` (United Kingdom) is home to three different locales - `cy-GB` (1106), `gd-GB` (1169) and `en-GB` (2057).

As far as performance goes, well... unless you can avoid *all* allocations in that `Where` of yours, there isn't much to tweak. Even a simple `string.Split` will likely cost you more than simply doing `new RegionInfo`. The culture data is cached, so there's only a memory cost associated with this kind of operation after the first time. And of course, again, there's nothing preventing you from building a lookup of your own, if you don't mind the memory cost.

Comment: Yes it's obvious now you say!